# Rscript executed on windows command line doesn't show any result

Tags: r, windows, cmd

I am trying to run very simple Rscript file on windows cmd.

The Rscript I am trying to test is as below:

```
setwd("C:\Users\Lily\Tutorial0")

Product <-function(a,b)
{
  p <- a*b
  return(p)
}

result <- Product(10,0.4);
print("Calculating the result...")
print(result);
```

In order to use command `Rscript`, I have added the Rscript.exe and R.exe's path on PATH variable as well since I installed R on D drive.

However, the Rscript command seemed to work but the result that I intended(which is "Calculating the result....4), didn't come out. Actually nothing came up but next line to input.

```
C:\Users\Lily>Rscript Tutorial0.R

C:\Users\Lily>Rscript
Usage: /path/to/Rscript [--options] [-e expr [-e expr2 ...] | file] [args]

--options accepted are
  --help              Print usage and exit
  --version           Print version and exit
  --verbose           Print information on progress
  --default-packages=list
                      Where 'list' is a comma-separated set
                        of package names, or 'NULL'
or options to R, in addition to --no-echo --no-restore, such as
  --save              Do save workspace at the end of the session
  --no-environ        Don't read the site and user environment files
  --no-site-file      Don't read the site-wide Rprofile
  --no-init-file      Don't read the user R profile
  --restore           Do restore previously saved objects at startup
  --vanilla           Combine --no-save, --no-restore, --no-site-file
                        --no-init-file and --no-environ

'file' may contain spaces but not shell metacharacters
Expressions (one or more '-e <expr>') may be used *instead* of 'file'
See also  ?Rscript  from within R
```

How can I show the result on window cmd?

[command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kBvn.png)
[second try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Lgit.png)

Comment: Surprising. I just tried the same using your code and it works perfectly well, though I have removed the `setwd` part. What happens when you a) run your script in RStudio? b) use `cat` instead of `print` and c) add `flush.console()`?

Comment: Additionally, in the command prompt at `C:\Users\Lily`, could you please write `type Tutorial0.R` and post a screenshot of the result?

Comment: @coffeinjunky a) In R studio, it works fine. b,c) I have tried this with Tutorial1 name but didn't work.

Comment: The result scrrenshot I have added in the post as 'second try'

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but it also strikes me the lines you have in the screenshot where you try to plot something can't work and must throw an error, yet you say it runs fine in RStudio.